# jquery animate opacity not working in table

Tags: jquery

i want to have a table of images, and when you hover over each image it will animate its opacity. the problem is it will only animate opacity on the FIRST image, and the rest will not be affected.

HTML:

```
<table id="pictures" align="center">

<tr>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
<td><img id="pics" src="img/post/shy_artwork.jpg"></img></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#pics").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity : 1, border : '17px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) solid'}, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity : 0.85, border : '17px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) solid'}, 300);
});
```

CSS:

```
img#pics
{
height:150px;
width:150px;
opacity:0.85;
border:17px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) solid;
}
```

how can i get this to work? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work only for the first image because you are using `id`'s. Id are meant to be unique and jQuery know that. So when using an id as selector it will do `document.getElementById(yourId)` which is a native javascript selector and also the fastest one since it return **only one element**.

That being said, you need to use class on your elements if you want it to work for every of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use classes - you cannot use multiple ids like that. The reason is that ids are meant to be unique... so once the first one is found, it sees no need to look for more.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/XZe8L/

I changed the image and opacity level so it's more obvious.

```
<table id="pictures" align="center">

<tr>
<td><img class="pics" src="http://simpsonsmania.wikispaces.com/file/view/BartSimpsonAni.gif/35178335/BartSimpsonAni.gif"></img></td>
<td><img class="pics" src="http://simpsonsmania.wikispaces.com/file/view/BartSimpsonAni.gif/35178335/BartSimpsonAni.gif"></img></td>
....
```